# How to handle consumer failures in queue-based systems?

Tags: architecture, message-queue, batch-processing

I have a rather conceptual question, which I hope won't be deemed too generic or too stupid :)

In an application where a data item needs to go through many steps(for example - step 1 - parsing from a CSV file and generating reports, step 2 - then running reports based on the reports generated in previous step, etc.), let's assume processing is implemented using persistent queue, such that when a new raw file is discovered, a message is placed in a queue asking to process said file. Message is picked by a consumer that processes the file and puts another message queueing the results of its work for the next step of processing and so on.

My question is - what are best practices for handling the failures in this process? Let's say a consumer on the step 1 fails completely.

Is it at all logic/efficient to implement such batch-processing on queue based architecture at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, queues are ok you also need an error queue where you'd put messages on problematic files and records

Note that complete failure is the easy case since you can just reprocess the whole file later (if it was a temporary problem) or disregard the file (if it is faulty). The more serious problem is partial failure where some of the records are problematic.

If a failure in one steps means that other steps have to be undone in some way you may want to  look at implementing it as a [saga](http://rgoarchitects.bit.ly/4xNwpp). If you want finer control on the process you may want to consider orchestration